# Play Framework: How to compile an application with the option "-Xlint:unchecked"?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

When I build application using Play Framework 2.3.8, I got this message. How can I add this option for compile?

```
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you building your application exactly?

Normally it's as simple as:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked
```

If you're using sbt then something like this should work:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked")
```

[Here's](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Basic-Def-Examples.html) a fuller example (with different javacOptions, though).